# Добавление объекта ImageIcon в документ Word

Tags: java, apache, poi

Скажите, имеется ли техническая возможность вставить изображение ImageIcon в документ Word с помощью Apache Poi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому-то поможет

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
            InputStream is = imageInput(foto);


            XWPFParagraph title = document.createParagraph();
            XWPFRun run = title.createRun();
            run.addPicture(is, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_GIF, "АЛПАТОВ", Units.toEMU(120), Units.toEMU(160));
            is.close();

private InputStream imageInput(ImageIcon foto) {
        try {
            Image fotoImage = foto.getImage();
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(fotoImage.getWidth(null), fotoImage.getHeight(null),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR);
            Graphics2D g2 = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
            g2.drawImage(fotoImage, null, null);
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", outputStream);
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
            return is;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```